# How to write strings into a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I am trying to create a csv file with a single column of file paths. I need a second column filled with ones.

The result I want to get is as follows;

```
./1/a_1.csv, 1
./1/a_2.csv, 1
./1/a_3.csv, 1
```

The code I tried is this;

```
import numpy as np

data=np.chararray((650,2), itemsize=20)

for i in range(1, 650):
    data[0][0]="./1/a_" + str(i) + ".csv"

np.savetxt("C:\\a.csv", data, delimiter = ",")
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Could you help?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't seem to work"? What happens? Do you get an error? If so, please post the error too, and the traceback, if any.

Comment: "TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S20') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e')". I was getting this error but the solution you have posted works so thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Numpy for this. Just do something like

```
with open('a.csv', 'w') as outf:
    for i in range(650):
        print('./1/a_%s.csv, 1' % (i + 1), file=outf)
```

and you're golden.

Comment: Interesting use of print. Is there any difference between your method and `with open('a.csv', 'w') as myfile:` `myfile.write('./1/a_%s.csv, 1')`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print explains the `file` parameter.  It says the `file` object must a have `write` method.  So in effect they are the same (for string output).

Comment: `print()` adds the newline by default, too; I didn't want to clutter the original code with the extra ` \n `

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about how the file is created (as long as it works), go for AKX's solution.

If you want to do it with Numpy, you need to get your dtype straight. `np.savetxt` has a default formatter which has trouble understanding the array you gave it.

This is how I managed to get your desired output:

```
data = np.empty((650,2),dtype="S20") # empty array of the correct datatype 

data[:,1] = '1' # set column 1 to '1' (as you noted)

for i in range(650):
    data[i][0] = "./1/a_" + str(i) + ".csv" # put your filenames into first column

np.savetxt(r"C:\a.csv", data, delimiter = ",", fmt="%s") # save it using %s formatter
```

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration of your loop, you only ever write to `data[0][0]`. You need to alter your loop to change the array position you're setting as you loop over the range.

Answer (score 1):

In csv file the delimiter is ";" not ",".

```
import numpy as np

data=np.chararray((650,2), itemsize=20)

for i in range(1, 650):
    data[0][0]="./1/a_" + str(i) + ".csv"

np.savetxt("C:\\a.csv", data, delimiter = ";")
```

Comment: The default delimiter is `","` because that's the most common one used and what ,many people think the "C" is ["CSV"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) stands for. However there is no standard, and `";"` is fine, as are many other characters.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Dataframes from the Pandas library. A similar approach to chitown88's answer, but more compact.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a list with paths to files named from 1 to 256
file_paths = ["./1/a_{}.csv".format(i) for i in range(1,257)]

# add the list to a Pandas Dataframe, the column name can be omitted
df = pd.DataFrame(data=file_paths, columns=['Paths'])

# add a column of 1's to the DataFrame
df['1'] = 1

# write the DataFrame without the indices and column names to a csv file using a specific separation character  
df.to_csv('C:\\a.csv', sep=',', index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score -3):

I personally like to store all my data into a dataframe and then at he very end, save it to a csv file, as opposed to writing after each iteration.

so I initialize a blank dataframe called `results`

then iterates through your range, creating your file_path string. Then I create that 1 row with the current file_name string and your 2nd column. That gets appended to the results dataframe, then moves on to the next item in your list/range. Continues that process until it's done, then saves the final results dataframe to file

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize an empty dataframe 
results = pd.DataFrame()

# iterates each element in the range list to form a row that is appended to the results dataframe
for i in range(1, 650):
    file_path="./1/a_" + str(i) + ".csv"
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[file_path, 1]], columns = ['file_path', 'col_2'])
    results = results.append(temp_df.reset_index(drop = True))

# after iterating through all the elements, saves completed results dataframe to file
results.to_csv("a.csv", index=False))
```

Comment: Can you please provide some information on what this code does/how it works? Code-only answers often don't shine as well as ones that are accompanied by explanations.